# Prevent visual reflow of the page when loading thumbnails

Tags: html, css, image

I'm loading multiple thumbnails per page, between 50 or 100.  Even if it's not necessary, i do want to supply some sort of height and width to the `<img>` element so it doesn't causes a visual reflow of the page once the images load.

I don't know the exact width or height of each image. I only know, for sure, that the image width and height will never be greater than 125px.
So, i can have images like 125x125, 100x80, 45x 90, etc... but never greater than 125 in width or height.

Is there a technique to prevent visual reflow of the page knowing what i've just mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: Exists any possibility to know the image sizes which you're listing? If you can get the sizes, you can apply the @Ally Ripp answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should wrap your  element in a  (or block type element) and set the min-width and min-height on the new div. If you want it to only take up the minimum space necessary, use 45 and 90 as the minumum. if you want it to take up the total possible space, use 125 as the minumum. like so:

```
<div class="img-holder>
  <img src="path/to/image" />
</div>
```

And in your css:

```
.img-holder {
  min-width: 45px;
  min-height: 90px;
 }
```

Comment: But if the image is bigger than the container the page will reflow.